# Working on Two/Multiple Web (Rails) Projects on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, web, command-line

I am currently working on a Rails web application on a Windows 8 laptop. I would like to start another personal web application. I tried doing so, but was warned that I should not do that since the windows command line would confuse my path settings (?). I need to be working on both projects side by side, and would like to know if and how I can achieve that.

Comment: As long as you alternate `rails server` depending on which app you're working on (or change the port for one of the apps somehow) I believe that you should be able to work on both.

Comment: Wouldn't I need different versions of ruby/rake/bundler as suggested by the answer below? What is a work-around for that?

Comment: If you are using the same versions of everything, which is totally acceptable to do, then you should be able to work on both simultaneously. Otherwise @Syl is probably correct.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I could make use of this tutorial if I have different versions: http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path settings for multiple parallel rails projects are usually problematic because you need to use different versions of ruby/bundler/rake for each project. Usually, to avoid thoses problems, on Linux systems you use RVM (ruby version manager) or rbenv. Similar tools exist for OSX. I am not sure they exist for Windows.

This is outside of your question, but i strongly recommend you to avoid using windows as your dev environment. I am also using windows on my main desktop. I tried to use Rails on windows, but it create too much problem and the documentation is sparse.

My solution to work on a Windows OS is a virtual machine with an Ubuntu Linux running my rails environment. I edit my file  with sublimetext from a network share on my VM, and a terminal allow me to do everything else.

EDIT :

More on the subject of a VM

Ruby and rails (and python and Django, and NodeJS and...) are designed to be used with a *Nix OS (include Linux and OSX). On the long run, I really recommend that you use a VM with a Linux.

Comment: I'm quite used to Windows and don't want to make a switch to a different operating system. It's hard to believe that a solution like RVM has not yet been made available for Windows. In your opinion, would switching to a different rails server depending on which app I am developing (as suggested by the comment above) allow me to work on different applications concurrently?

Comment: Do you think pik is helpful to use for Windows?

Comment: I do not use rails on windows, all i know is that each time you will encounter an installation/configuration error on windows there will be a lot less info than on a Linux/OSX conf.